# Access Nest Thermostat Extra Temperature Sensors?

Tags: nest-device-access

So, I managed to get setup the Nest Device Access Console, Smart Device Management API, and the Cloud Pub/Sub API setup, so I can see my Nest Thermostat.  Everything is working there.

My question is related to the Nest Thermostat Temperature Sensors.  I have 3 extra sensors in my house, and I want to be able to read those sensors over the API.  When I query the thermostat, I get the master temperature from the active sensor, but I cannot access any of the other sensors.  Is there a way to get access to those sensors?  The Nest app can see them, so why can't our apps?

https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/api/thermostat

Answer (score 0):

The [Supported Devices](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/supported-devices#thermostats) page mentions:

> Note: Temperature sensors are not supported in the Device Access program.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).